# rails5.1で、即時500エラー終了したい

Tags: ruby-on-rails

GET引数が仕様通りではない→クラック開始だ→即拒否、
を実現するため、
phpでの

```
header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
exit;
```

と同様のことを、
rails5.1のcontroller内で行おうとして、

```
if @entry.blank?
  render text: "error"
  throw(:abort)
end
```

と書いてみたのですが、意図通り即時終了になってくれません。
rails5.1で実現可能でしょうか？

- 2017-12-11追記  
  （コメント欄だとコードブロックが使えず改行も効かない為、ソースコード載せるのが不可能でした）  
  rails 5.1 の  
  rails generate scaffold entry title:string body:integer  
  が生成する app/controllers/entry_controller.rb は、以下のように、  
  「EntriesController.set_entry で @entry を取得する」  
  ようになっていまして、  
  （それ以前のバージョンの動きはわかりません。rails入門してまだ一週間経ってないので...）  
  そこで throw(:abort) しても効果が無い、という話でした。

app/controllers/entry_controller.rb

```
class EntriesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_entry, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /entries/1
  def show
  end

  # GET /entries/new
  def new
    ...
  end

  # GET /entries/1/edit
  def edit
    ...
  end

  # POST /entries
  def create
    ...
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /entries/1
  def update
    ...
  end

    # DELETE /entries/1
  def destroy
    ...
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_entry
      @entry = Entry.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def entry_params
    ...
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

例外を投げれば 500 になりますので、以下のような感じでいかがでしょう?

```
def set_entry
  @entry = Entry.find(params[:id])
  if @entry.blank?
    raise 'error'
  end
end
```

`@entry.blank?` は真にはならないと思いますが、他の条件なら使えるのでは、と思います。

Comment: 最初に↑のように書いたら、その場で停止せずにcontroller後の処理であるview処理に突入してしまい、view側の entry.titelとかで「そんな要素はありません」エラーになりました。で、もっと前段階でerror exit 出来ないものか、というのが当質問の趣旨です。

Comment: @sreinfrasystemjp その「もっと前段階」というのはこの場所で正しいと思います。ここで例外を起こせば 500 になり、action も view も処理されないはずです。`set_entry` が実行されているかどうか、また、`@entry` がどんな値になっているのか、確認されてはいかがでしょう?

Comment: 勘違いしてました。render&throw ではなく raise を使え、という話ですね。raiseは意図通りその場で終了してくれました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

```
render text: 'error', status: 500
```

でどうでしょうか。

Comment: 変更してみましたが、controller後の処理であるview処理に突入してしまう現象は改善しませんでした。

Comment: 一応確認ですが、@entryがblankであることに間違いないのでしょうか？単にifブロック内を通ってないということはありませんか？

Comment: private set_XXX 側では機能しない、という動きでした。
indexやshow側では機能しました。

Comment: private setxxxって・・・いきなりなんのことですか？他の人が読んでも意味が分からなければ、このサイトに載せる意味がありませんよ。